# Paypal request has failed with system error?

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have Implemented Paypal SDK in my iOS Application and When I make request to Paypal Server, I am getting error as below

```
 **PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: UNKNOWN_ERROR - System error (UNKNOWN_ERROR). Please try again later. (400) | PayPal Debug-ID: b2ebd65f0347d [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.6.1]**
```

Please help me to sort out this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Dave from PayPal here.

We have occasionally seen this sort of unexplained error before, and are trying to get to the bottom of it.

Could you please open this a new issue at the [PayPal-iOS-SDK repository](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues)? There we can work with you to try to pin down why this is happening.

Thanks!